# In cloned div I cant call jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

Hi Am working on a mock test portal and In this Portal there is section called Combination of multiple choice where we are using both check box and radio button.
*Coming to the scenario* I have to add/append a particular Div class to the same Div class more than one's.Div class contain checkbox etc. In order to add/append i have used *clone in jquery*.In this checkbox has a jquery function is working in parent Div class where it is not working in child(cloned).Hope to get a better solution for this scenario Thank You all.

```
    <div id="addresses">
            <div class="address" id="address0">
            <div class="join">
            <div class="col s12 m12">
            <div class="card-panel lighthen-4  black-text"  style="width:850px;">
        <div class="row">
        <p><span style="background-color:Black;color:white;font-
        size:25px">Question</span><div id="number"></div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <textarea id="textarea14" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="textarea14">Question</label>
        </div>

            <div class="switch">
            <label>
            Off
            <input class="checker" type="checkbox" id="checker0"/>
            <span class="lever"></span>
            On
            </label>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

            $("#checker0").click(function () {


            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

            $("#cmcq0").hide();
            $("#mcq0").show();
            } else {

            $("#cmcq0").show();
            $("#mcq0").hide();
            }
            });
            });
            var rowNum = 0;
        <div class="checker" id="mcq0"style="display:none;">
<p>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="test9" />
<label for="test9">Choice A<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea15" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="test10" />
<label for="test10">Choice B<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea16" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="test11" />
<label for="test11">Choice C<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea17" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="test12" />
<label for="test12">Choice D<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea18" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

</p>

</div>
</div>


<div class="checker" id="cmcq0">
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test13" />
<label for="test13">Choice A<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea19" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test14" />
<label for="test14">Choice B<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea20" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test15" />
<label for="test15">Choice C<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea21" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test16" />
<label for="test16">Choice D<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea22" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
</p>





</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="addmoreadd">
<button type="button" class="addmore">Add More Address</button>
</div>


        $("body").on("click", ".addmore", function() {
        rowNum++;
        var $address = $(this).parents('.address');
        var nextHtml = $address.clone();
        nextHtml.attr('id', 'address' + rowNum);
        nextHtml.find('checker').prop('id', 'checker' + rowNum,'mcq' + rowNum);
        var hasRmBtn = $('.rmbtn', nextHtml).length > 0;
        if (!hasRmBtn) {
        var rm = "<button type='button' class='rmbtn'>Remove</button>"
        $('.addmoreadd', nextHtml).append(rm);
        }
        $address.after(nextHtml); 
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".rmbtn", function() {
        $(this).parents('.address').remove();
        });
        });

            </script>
```

Comment: check my answer, there are few problems with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same `id` for more than one element which is not a good practice.Element IDs should be unique within the entire document. Instead, you can use `classes` like this. If you will use same `id` the click event will occur only for the first element in the document with that `id`. Also, use `on` event listener to execute events for dynamically appended elements.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".checker", function() {


  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

    $(this).closest(".address").find(".cmcq0").hide();
    $(this).closest(".address").find(".mcq0").show();
  } else {

    $(this).closest(".address").find(".cmcq0").show();
    $(this).closest(".address").find(".mcq0").hide();
  }
});

var rowNum = 0;
$("body").on("click", ".addmore", function() {
  rowNum++;
  var $address = $(this).parents('.address');
  var nextHtml = $address.clone();
  nextHtml.attr('id', 'address' + rowNum);
  nextHtml.find('checker').prop('id', 'checker' + rowNum, 'mcq' + rowNum);
  var hasRmBtn = $('.rmbtn', nextHtml).length > 0;
  if (!hasRmBtn) {
    var rm = "<button type='button' class='rmbtn'>Remove</button>"
    $('.addmoreadd', nextHtml).append(rm);
  }
  $address.after(nextHtml);
});

$("body").on("click", ".rmbtn", function() {
  $(this).parents('.address').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addresses">
  <div class="address" id="address0">
    <div class="join">
      <div class="col s12 m12">
        <div class="card-panel lighthen-4  black-text" style="width:850px;">
          <div class="row">
            <p><span style="background-color:Black;color:white;font-
            size:25px">Question</span>
              <div id="number"></div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <textarea id="textarea14" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="textarea14">Question</label>
              </div>

              <div class="switch">
                <label>
                Off
                <input class="checker checker0" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="lever"></span>
                On
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="checker mcq0" style="display:none;">
                <p>
                  <input type="radio" name="group" id="test9" />
                  <label for="test9">Choice A<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea15" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

                </p>
                <p>
                  <input type="radio" name="group" id="test10" />
                  <label for="test10">Choice B<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea16" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

                </p>
                <p>
                  <input type="radio" name="group" id="test11" />
                  <label for="test11">Choice C<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea17" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

                </p>
                <p>
                  <input type="radio" name="group" id="test12" />
                  <label for="test12">Choice D<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea18" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>

                </p>

              </div>
          </div>


          <div class="checker cmcq0">
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" id="test13" />
              <label for="test13">Choice A<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea19" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" id="test14" />
              <label for="test14">Choice B<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea20" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" id="test15" />
              <label for="test15">Choice C<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea21" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" id="test16" />
              <label for="test16">Choice D<div class="input-field col s12"><textarea id="textarea22" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea></div></label>
            </p>





          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="addmoreadd">
      <button type="button" class="addmore">Add More Address</button>
    </div>
```

**P.S.** Changed id  `#cmcq0` to class `.cmcq0`,  `#mcq0` to class `.mcq0` ,  and added `on` event listener for `.checker`

Comment: @Tamil Glad I helped

Comment: I got a new challenge in this scenario that after entering the data in parent div class and if i add another div (cloned div) data that is entered in parent class is replicated in child how to overcome this challenge? sir

Answer (score 0):

A jsfiddle could help,

Try `$(document).on('event','#element', function() { /* code here */ } );`

For dynamically loaded elements.